# Storing regex pattern strings in an array

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have some regex pattern strings that I'd like to pass to other methods inside an array (or some other collection).

Based on the comments,my initial question was not clear enough. Here's a Unit Test that explains exactly what I try to do.

In short, I'm trying to replace a substring (based on a regex pattern) with another regex pattern.

```
        var mainPattern = @"\{[\w]*\}";
        string replacePattern = @"\d{4}";

        var patternArray = new string[] { replacePattern };
        // patternArray[0] == "\\d{4}"

        string input = "fd/{ddf}/dfdf";
        string expected = @"fd/\d{4}/dfdf";

        var match = Regex.Match(input, mainPattern);
        // match.Value == "{ddf}"
        var output = Regex.Replace(input, match.Value, patternArray[0]);
        // output == "fd/\\d{4}/dfdf"

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, output);
```

The problem is in the final output where it contains a double backslash (because that's how the replace string looks like).

I hope the problem becomes more clear.

I'm think that I'm complicating too much. I'm not familiar with all Regex features?

Comment: `"\\"` and `@"\"` are the same. `string regex = @"\d{4}";` is a perfectly valid regex.

Comment: Alternatively, You can use Regex array.

Comment: I think the string is just converted from a verbatim string to a normal one, to be stored in the array as string. I don't think this causes your problem. Please show the complete code, because `Regex.Replace(string input, string pattern, string replacement)` I am not sure if that fits to your `Regex.Replace(inputstring, matches[i].Value, patterns[i])`

Comment: everything's fine with the regex pattern: @"\d{4}" == "\\d{4}"

Comment: Thanks, apparently the question was indeed not clear enough and I updated it to represent more the full scope of the problem.

Comment: I did a `Console.WriteLine(output);` and it gave me `fd/\d{4}/dfdf`.

Comment: `expected` and `output` **are** equal in your code when I run it.  Are you seeing a different result?

Comment: Argh, this is again one of these problems that, when simplifying, always work. I can't seem to explain it without disposing proprietary code.

Comment: I think you have the right approach.  Keep writing unit testing code to try to identify the real source of the issue.

Comment: If the code you posted works, then the problem isn't with this section of code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's your problem - the double slash is <strike>an artifact of the VS debugger</strike> equivalent to your verbatim string.

If you click the little magnifying glass for the "text visualizer", you'll see it doesn't actually have double-slashes.

[image]

Comment: Not very sure. When I use it in the replace, it does consider both backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

As weird as it may look, on my test it worked like a charm.
Which version of .NET and Visual Studio you are using?

[image]